# Get values from nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have this Hash that I use store values and if the values are not found to get default values:

```
AMOUNT = {
  EUR: {
    eps:         { AT: 1_00 },
    safetypay:   { PE: 15_000_00, CR: 5_000_00, BE: 15_000_00, },
    przelewy24:  5_00,
    qiwi:        5_00,
    bcmc:        { AT: 1_00, BE: 1_00 },
    giropay:     { DE: 1_00 },
    ideal:       { NL: 1_00 },
    mybank:      { IT: 1_00, FR: 1_00 },
  },
  CZK: {
    trustpay:   { CZ: 20_00 }
  }
}.with_indifferent_access
```

I would like to get values based on the keys so I tried this:

```
def amount_for(payment_type, country, currency)
  payment_amount = AMOUNT.dig(currency, payment_type, country) if payment_type.is_a?(Hash)
  payment_amount ||= AMOUNT.dig(currency, payment_type)
  payment_amount ||= 1
end
```

But I get for result not number but `{"AT"=&gt;100, "BE"=&gt;100}`. If I remove the check `if payment_type.is_a?(Hash)` I get exception `Integer does not have #dig method (RuntimeError)`

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: How do you call the `amount_for` method, i.e. what are the arguments that lead to the unexpected result / error?

Answer (score 1):

`payment_type` will be e.g. `"AT"` - it's the argument you pass into your function, it will never be a Hash.

This rewrite should do what you want:

```
def amount_for(payment_type, country = nil, currency = nil)
  path = [payment_type, country, currency].compact
  obj = AMOUNT
  obj = obj[path.shift] while Hash === obj && !path.empty?
  return obj || 1
end
```

Alternately, this is rather similar to the code you wrote:

```
def amount_for(payment_type, country = nil, currency = nil)
  tmp = AMOUNT.dig(payment_type, country, currency)
  return tmp if tmp
  tmp = AMOUNT.dig(payment_type, country)
  return tmp if tmp
  tmp = AMOUNT.dig(payment_type)
  return tmp if tmp
  return 1
end
```

Comment: can you give me some hint how to fix it please?

Comment: The last line _was_ a hint. You need to change `if payment_type.is_a?(Hash)` to `if AMOUNT[payment_type].is_a?(Hash)`.

Comment: Strange, I still get value `{"NL"=&gt;100}`

Comment: Oops, I overlooked something. I should have said `AMOUNT[currency][payment_type]`, but that would have been wrong, for various reasons involving exceptional circumstances. I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: Hm... I get always 1 for amount in every case.